# Why does the Selenium-Python WebDriverWait not work as documented?

Tags: python, selenium

I have a very complex `py.test` script that uses selenium to test a non-public webpage. In that test script I have the following code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
result = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', "//span[contains(text(), 'Start simulation')]/..")))
```

According to the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) (or [here](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)), I expect that piece of code to 'wait' for a maximum of 1 second. However, it is stuck there for about 256 seconds!

Why is that? How can that happen?

Versioning information: 

 `- pytest==3.6.1 
 - selenium==3.14.1`

Comment: Just note that this is not the official documentation. It is clearly mentioned on the home page https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html

Comment: So where is the official documentation then. It is not clearly mentioned on the home page https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html.

Comment: No. Nothing mentions where to find the official documentation.

Comment: The official documentation i believe is at https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/

Comment: 'contribute', 'fork'? what?

Comment: @Alex did you try to set page load timeout: `driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)`?

Answer (score 3):

Please check if you have an implicit wait somewhere in your code. Its a good idea not to mix [implicit](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits) and [explicit](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) waits. One known issue is that if you have implicit wait somewhere else, that might affect the explicit wait time.

https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2948

Comment: The wait is absolutely definitively with 100% certainty in this line of code: `result = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', "//span[contains(text(), 'Start simulation')]/..")))`

Comment: @Alex You don't know that... just because it *fails* there, doesn't mean that it's not due to a bad interaction with implicit waits. Do you have an implicit wait set? The docs clearly state not to mix the two.

Answer (score 2):

`WebDriverWait` only starts waiting after the page is loaded (browser returns `document.readyState == 'complete'`). If the page load takes 256 seconds, the `WebDriverWait` hasn't even started yet.

Answer (score 0):

Just Check If you try instead of this.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
result = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(('xpath', "//span[contains(text(), 'Start simulation')]/..")))
```

Try this to make any difference.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1)
    result = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(text(), 'Start simulation')]/..")))
```

Comment: same behavior as before. Waits only 60 seconds now.

Comment: well could you please share html part of the script you are trying?

Comment: good question. I cannot. The whole browser is unresponsive. I am unable to open a developer console. Interesting...

Comment: As it turns out, it seems to be a problem with the page I am trying to load. It essentially blocks everything, including selenium somehow. So your question regarding the page content brought me in the right direction.